# Swift KVO changeHandler not being called

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I have the following code to refresh multiple items. This all happens asynchronously.

```
func refresh(_ types: [DataTypes], callback: ((String) -> Void)?) {
    let refreshOperationQueue: OperationQueue = OperationQueue()
    let operations: [Operation] = types.map({ RefreshItem.init(type: $0) })
    refreshOperationQueue.addOperations(operations, waitUntilFinished: false)
    let _: NSKeyValueObservation = refreshOperationQueue.observe(\.operationCount) { _, _ in
        if refreshOperationQueue.operationCount == 0 {
            callback?("Success")
        }
    }
}
```

It reloads the data fine. But the problem is the `observe` `changeHandler` is never being called.

I'm assuming this is because that observer is being released in memory (but I could be totally wrong). If this is the case I'm not sure how to fix this in an efficient manner. If I make it a higher scope then it can only handle 1 refresh at a time, which isn't the cleanest solution.

Basically I want `callback?("Success")` to run when the `OperationQueue` is complete.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed that the observer is being released in memory. You need to store it somewhere. If you want to store an arbitrary number of them, just declare an array somewhere higher up in the scope, and add your observer to the array.

Alternatively, you could simply add a new `BlockOperation` to the operation queue, and add all your other operations as dependencies. This will cause your completion operation to run after everything else is done.